# Android image attachement in email

Tags: android, android-camera, email-attachments

I have to e-mail an image after taking picture from camera. When I print the address of the  required image it prints correct which is stored in the `filePath` variable; it shows /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/camera/2013-04-2921.33.45.jpg, but  when I send it, it shows the attachment in the application but after sending the mail, the receiver does not receive the attachment.

The basic structure of my application is:

1. On the first screen of my app, the user clicks on a button, TAKE PICTURE.
2. The default camera app of the phone comes and the user takes a picture.
3. The user is then asked to enter his name and his phone number.
4. The name, phone-number and the image must be attached to an email to be sent to a predefined address. (gmail android app)
5. The name and phone number are coming in the email body. Also, the the image shows attached. But on sending the mail, the received mail does not have the attached image.

Here is the code of the attachment:

```
public class INF extends Activity {
String pic,fullPath;

private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.in);
    final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
    final EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
    Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);

    getLastImageId();


    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("plain/text");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"pravind.india@gmail.com"});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Information");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Name:"+et.getText().toString()+'\n'+"Mobile No."+et2.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(fullPath));

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "send email...."));
        }
    });


}
private int getLastImageId(){
    final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+" DESC";
    Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns, null, null, imageOrderBy);
    if(imageCursor.moveToFirst()){
        int id = imageCursor.getInt(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
         fullPath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastImageId::id " + id);
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastImageId::path " + fullPath);
        imageCursor.close();
        return id;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

}
```

`getLastImageId` stores the path of the last image taken by the camera in variable `fullPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrong is that you have chosen the type of the intent as `text` not `octet-stream` so
you have to do this

```
setType("application/octet-stream")
```

instead of this

```
setType("plain/text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add permission access to media store, try this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
sendIntent.setType("image/png"); //set content type
```

check uri right working or no look here:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/1");
```

or

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://mnt/sdcard/test.jpg");
```

or

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test.jpg");
```

Example: [How to send an MMS Programmatically in Android](http://sumitsharma1900.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-send-mms-programmatically-in.html)

If don't help, send your data via java mail transport see this:

[Using JavaMail to Send Mail](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail#Multi_Part_Messages)